# PHP Replace quotation marks surrounding a string

Tags: php, regex, pdo

I am trying to make my PDO query dynamic by running some logical operations before building my query.

However when the query is currently built no results are returned because the column name I am referencing in surrounded in quotations ( at least I believe this is the problem ), how would I go about removing quotation marks surrounding my string?

Logical Operation & Query

```
       // Logical comparison
       if($psiA >= $psiB){
            $highestPsi = "high_psi";
       } else {
            $highestPsi = "flow_psi";
       }

       if($gpmA >= $gpmB){
            $highestGpm = "high_gpm";
       } else {
            $highestGpm = "flow_gpm";
       }

       var_dump($highestGpm);
       var_dump($highestPsi);

       // Set up query variables
       if( $pVal <= 0 && $gVal <= 0) {
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM pumps WHERE pump_type = :pType AND :thePsi >= :pVal AND :theGpm >= :gVal AND pump_category = :cVal";
       } else {
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM pumps WHERE pump_type = :pType AND :thePsi >= :pVal AND :theGpm >= :gVal AND pump_category = :cVal";
           var_dump($sql);
       }

        // Build and execute query
       $stmt = $connection->prepare( $sql );

       $stmt->bindParam(':pType', $pType, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $stmt->bindParam(':pVal', $pVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $stmt->bindParam(':gVal', $gVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $stmt->bindParam(':cVal', $cVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $stmt->bindParam(':thePsi', $highestPsi, PDO::PARAM_STR);
       $stmt->bindParam(':theGpm', $highestGpm, PDO::PARAM_STR);

       $stmt->execute(array( 
                      'pType'   => $pType, 
                      'pVal'    => $pVal, 
                      'gVal'    => $gVal,
                      'cVal'    => $cVal,
                      'thePsi'  => $highestPsi,
                      'theGpm'  => $highestGpm
        ));
```

I know that the dump is returning the correct column names, I am certain that I need to perform some sort of regex to strip the quotes for this to work.

Any pointers would be most appreciated.

Comment: Well first you're binding values twice. Either bindParam or an array in execute.

Comment: are you binding a field name as a parameter? because that wont work, just concat it into your query string, as long as its not user input, its injection safe (unless you do something stupid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO's prepared statement can represent a **data literal** only. Thus, a developer have to take care of identifiers oneself - PDO offers **no help** for the matter.

So, you have to either use any other library instead of PDO, such as [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pumps WHERE 
        pump_type = ?s AND ?n >= ?s AND ?n >= ?s AND pump_category = ?s";
$data = $db->getAll($sql, $pType, $highestPsi, $pVal, $highestGpm, $gVal, $cVal);
```

Or you have to format your identifiers manually. To format an identifier, one have to apply these 2 rules:

- Enclose identifier in backticks.
- Escape backticks inside by doubling them.

After such formatting, it is safe to insert the $table variable into query. So, the code would be:

```
$psi = "`".str_replace("`","``",$highestPsi)."`";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pumps WHERE pump_type = :pType AND $psi ...";
```

Comment: Thankyou! I shall attempt to get this working with your feedback, much appreciated.

Comment: May I query why :pType is now surrounded in quotes? Is that the standard PDO format or is that optional?

Comment: just a copy-paste bug. there should be NO quotes at all

Answer (score 0):

Nope, quotes are not really the problem. The problem is that you cannot bind any *structural elements* like column or table names. You can only bind *values*. You'll have to do with good old string concatenation/`sprintf` if you need to dynamically alter column names.

Comment: And do extensive validation!

Comment: ...or at least whitelisting.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks for your response! I'll try fathom a solution )